# Cakephp 3 : How to insert data on db from a behavior

Tags: cakephp, orm, save, behavior, cakephp-3.x

I've created a custom behavior on my CakePHP3 project and I would like to insert data on db from this behavior

Here is an clean exemple of my behavior, the function is well called and save of the form but the ADD Articles request doesn't work...

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class HistorizeBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity)
    {
        $this->historize($event, $entity);
    }

    public function historize(Event $event, Entity $entity) {
        $articlesTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles');
        $article = $articlesTable->newEntity();

        $article->title = 'A New Article';
        $article->body = 'This is the body of the article';
        $articlesTable->save($article);
    }
}
```

There is no error, no warning...but the data isn't saved..

Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you actually added the behavior to any table? Just creating the class by itself doesn't do anything. Also, you won't get any error or warning from this even if it runs and fails to insert, because you're not checking the results of the save call; it won't generate an error by itself, you'd need to do that explicitly.

Comment: Yes of course, the behavior is added to a table and if i die() on the historize() function i can see that the function is called correctly but the insert doesn't work... is it possible to insert data like that from a behavior ?

Comment: It's definitely possible. I'm guessing you have a validation issue that you're not detecting because you're not checking the return value from `->save`. Try `if (!$articlesTable->save($article) { debug($article->errors()); }`

Comment: that's where I have a problem, it's that there is no error... 

if (!$articlesTable->save($article))
        {
            debug($article->errors());
        }
        else
            debug("works well ");

the renderer displays "works well" but nothing is recorded in the db! 

and if I put exactly the same code in a controller, the record is well registered in the db, so it is not a problem of table or model

That's turn me crazy !

Comment: @GregSchmidt I see that you are a CakePHP expert, I am the only developer in my company who knows Cake and sometimes we are looking for freelancers for bigger projects, can we talk in private?

Comment: I would see if you can enable some SQL logging. Maybe this is succeeding, but inside of a transaction that ends up getting rolled back? https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging

Comment: Pretty swamped with work at the moment, not looking to take on other freelance jobs, sorry.

Comment: There's quite a few things that could go wrong here, for example since you're in beforeSave(), you are likely inside of a transaction, so whether something will be saved, will depend on whether the transaction succeeds (eg the parent save). Have you checked [**debug kit**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html) for the generated SQL queries?